# Updating an uncustomized master page deployed as a wsp solution

Tags: master-page, solution-package, event-receivers, farm-solution, custom-masterpage

I deployed an uncustomized master page as a SP 2010 Server farm solution using these instructions http://plekky.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11

Now I need to update the master page. I edited it and *had to* create a new solution. I retracted and removed the original solution and added and deployed the new solution but it did not update the master page.

Where is the master page?

Why won't it update?

Answer (score 2):

1. I think you DON'T need to deploy a whole new solution to replace master page.
2. Make sure the updated master page is deployed on SharePoint root
3. You also need to make sure that master page is not customized. I have observed that, even if you did not customize the master page explicitly, if you copied from SharePoint Designer, it may include following lines in master page and once you deploy it in master page gallery, the master page is treated as customized and subsequent change on SharePoint root will NOT matter. So make sure such lines were not included when you originally deployed the master page.

> ```
> <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint"/>
> <meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"/>
> ```

Comment: 1. I cannot find the original solution so I sort of need to make a new one to replace the page. Is there a GUID or something that is not matching?

Comment: 2. What do you mean, "sharepoint root"?

Comment: 3. Those meta tags are not present. Do I need an event receiver to update the master page OnFeatureActivated?

Comment: When you deploy solution, sharepoint deploys different files in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14 - that's sharepoint root. your files typically go in FEATURE subdirecory. If your master page is not customized, just redeplying updatde master page (via solution) should be fine.